# What is better way to implement category selection?

Tags: forms, gui-design, android, mobile-application

I am developing an android app and currently have a AutoCompletEditText implemented for selecting source of meme. However I want to limit source selection to limited number of options and therefore it becomes dropdown menu which takes a lot of space and unnecesary opens keyboard. Because of this, I was wondering, what is a better way to implement category selection? Below is example of the screen.

[image: Example of the implemented screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify how many items there were initially, and how many items the user can check. You can use a listbox if there are more than 15 items. [Here is a guide from NNG](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/listbox-dropdown/) about when to use a listbox vs when to use a dropdown list.

Modern platforms usually use listboxes too for categories and filters, but in a slightly different form called chips. This is an example from LinkedIn:

[image]

Here the selected chips are highlighted in green, and the selectable ones aren't highlighted at all.